# Exception "Bad data" when decrypt string in c# 3.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-3.5

Please give proper solution for below i can't able to decrypt my key.
Exception thrown "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

```
public static string EncryptText(string text)   
    {   
        string encryptedText = "";
        CspParameters cspParam = new CspParameters();
        cspParam.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParam);  
        byte[] byteInput = (System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text));    
        rsa.FromXmlString (GetPubKey() );
        byte[] byteEncrypted = rsa.Encrypt(byteInput, false);   
        encryptedText = (System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(byteEncrypted));
        return encryptedText;
    }

    public static string DecryptText(string text)   
    {
        CspParameters cspParam = new CspParameters();
        cspParam.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;       

        string encryptedText = null;    
        byte[] byteEncryptedString = (System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text));

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa3 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParam);            
        rsa3.FromXmlString (GetPriKey() );  
        byte[] byteDecryptedString = rsa3.Decrypt(byteEncryptedString, false);
        encryptedText = (System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(byteDecryptedString));
        return encryptedText;

    }
```

Here is my source code.

thanks.

Comment: it's working fine in 1.1,2.0 but when i migrate in 3.5 it is not working

Comment: what is a test data ?